# How to override the get and post behavior of the DispatcherServlet?

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I am using the Spring MVC controllers for REST services. I want to override the GET and POST behavior of the DispatcherServlet. I want to execute some custom logic when some condition is met during GET and POST request, otherwise fallback on the DispatcherServlet implementation.

I implemented custom serlvet that is derived from Spring's DispatcherServlet. There are methods doGet() and doPost() on the HttpServlet interface but it seems that those methods have been declared as final either in DispatcherServlet or one of its base class. Hence I could not override doGet() and doPost().

From the documentation, I figured out two methods - doService() and doDispatch() that could be overridden. I am confused about the difference between those two methods.

1. Which method - doService() or doDispatch() should I override?
2. What is the difference between doService() and doDispatch()?
3. How to figure out what http request - GET or POST it is?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of behavior do you want to override? Cannot you do it using filters or interceptors?

Comment: I want to inspect the request payload and headers and then take an appropriate action. There could be many approaches for achieving the same thing. If this approach is not correct, then I can look into other approaches. Is there anything wrong in overriding the GET and POST behavior of the DispatcherServlet? This is a kind of small POC and not a production implementation.

Comment: _inspect the request payload and headers_ Isn't that what `@RequestMapping` is for?  Can you give an example of a different action depending on request payload that would need more than 1 controller method?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is to create a [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html).

Note, however, that inspecting request payload is not a simple thing per se, because once you read the payload you cannot "unread" it without extra effort. See, for example, [How can I log RESTful post data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371168/how-can-i-log-restful-post-data/12371835#12371835)

But overriding methods of `DispatcherServlet` instead of using filters won't make it simplier anyway, it just makes things less clear and violates [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting filter approach. However, for now, I want to stick with custom DispatcherServlet approach. I might have a need to check different conditions and perform different actions for each http verb.