# Is there a way to access the body of a POST petition in a ExceptionHandler?

Tags: java, spring-boot

In a Spring Boot API Rest app I have a `ExceptionHandler` for a given `RestController`. This controller has a `@RequestBody` anotation that is a `String` in one of its methods.

```
@RestController
public class FooController {
    @PostMapping("/my_url")
    public ResponseEntity myMethod(@RequestBody String param) { 
        ....
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({MyCustomException.class})
    public ResponseEntity handleMyCustomException(MyCustomException ex) {
        ...
    }

}
```

I'm not able to access the aforementioned `String` in the `@ExceptionHandler` method (that corresponds to the body of the `POST` petition as the title says)

I can set the `param` variable in the `WebRequest` and then retrieve it the `handle` method but this seems a very hacky way to achieve it.

Is there a solution provided by the framework to access the body of the `POST` petition in a `ExceptionHandler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question you are asking is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502332/how-to-get-the-requestbody-in-an-exceptionhandler-spring-rest).
Unfortunately, there does not seem to have an elegant and easy solution.

Since you are throwing a custom exception, may be you could consider adding an attribute in the exception to hold that extra information (i.e. param).

Comment: The answer that you provided is what I am refering to in the question (setting the req as parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Is that you are looking for?

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

/**Here you can inject any you spring beans**/

  @ExceptionHandler({ MyCustomException.class })
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidRequest(RuntimeException exc, WebRequest request) {
    MyCustomException exception = (MyCustomException) exc;
    /**here you can do watewer you want with an exception and a body**/
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    /**here you have to create some response objects if needed**/
    YourExceptionWrapper error = new YourExceptionWrapper(exception.getMessage());
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    /**and then send a bad request to a front-end**/
    return handleExceptionInternal(exc, error, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
  }
}
```