# How to get the @RequestBody in an @ExceptionHandler (Spring REST) 2.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-security

I know [How to get the @RequestBody in an @ExceptionHandler (Spring REST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502332/how-to-get-the-requestbody-in-an-exceptionhandler-spring-rest) exists but I am looking for a slightly different solution.  When my service gets a 403 it does not make it to my @Controller class.  Thus, how can I still grab something out of the incoming request body, since this scenario would never actually hit my code?  It only ever hits the generated CGLIB code.

Comment: for 403 in  particular, i would recommend this: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring#denied

Comment: Which part of that article do recommend for this issue?

Comment: the linked: #denied - Chapter 6 :) ...6.2!

Comment: I had read that part, and that is basically what I am doing.  The issue is, how do I get the @RrequestBody from that?  Any object input to this service has a parent class in which a unique ID is required input by the client.   I need to grab that ID from the input request, so I can log it before I return the error.  So when my consumer complains of an issue for that specific ID, I can tell them they got a 403.

Comment: Once you have a `HttpServletRequest` (injected into your error handler), you can try to ["Get the POST request body from HttpServletRequest"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8100634/592355).

Comment: I tired that too, but keep getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: getInputStream() has already been called for this request

Comment: this means: someone/some filter/interceptor has already accessed `request.getReader()` ... :-(

Comment: Yup I figured as much :( Problem is, its gotta be some spring magic doing it, because I haven even gotten to my code yet, nor do I have any other interceptors :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I was able to solve the issue by creating a class that extends `RequestBodyAdviceAdapter`.

Comment: Brian could you please add some more details about the solution?