# How to get access to access request body inside Exception Handler

Tags: java, spring-boot

We have a spring boot app and our controller expects an XML Document element in one of our end points:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/api/v1/do-stuff",
        consumes = APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
        produces = APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<JAXBElement<my.company.stuff.resposnse.Document>> doStuff(
        @RequestBody JAXBElement<my.company.stuff.request.Document> requestBody,
        Principal principal) throws Exception {

    // Doing some suff here and returning the result
    return stuffService.doStuff(...);
}
```

We have our own instance of Jaxb2Marshaller where we set the schemas for both request document and response document to be used for marshalling and un-marshalling between request and response bodies and our domain objects. When the request comes the spring boot framework will do the conversion between the request body and and the domain request document. Sometimes the request body does not pass XSD schema validation and such it does not even reach our controller.

The exception thrown is passed to our custom extension of `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` where we would like to create the most meaningful error response for our application clients:

```
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        // Getting access to the request body would be very beneficial here
    }
```

Our issue is that sometimes the exception passed to our handler does not have enough details and we would like to be able to access the request body in order to be able to customise our response to the client. However, the input stream of the request is no longer accessible because it was already read from part of the schema validation (conversion) processing so any attempt to  access it this way fails.

On the other hand whaat we are trying to achieve is very common sense and just wondering if we took the wrong approach and what would be a better design to achieve the same thing. Changing the controller to expect a plain text and validate and convert it to the request document inside the controller is not really an option.

Thank you in advance or your inputs.

Comment: Hi @Julian, I have same problem. Did you find a solution for this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a request scoperd entity to keep requst body,

```
@Component
@RequestScope
public class RequestDetails {
    private JAXBElement<my.company.stuff.request.Document> requestBody;
    //getter setter
}
```

Use this in the controller to set request body,

```
@Inject
RequestDetails requestDetails;

public ResponseEntity<JAXBElement<my.company.stuff.resposnse.Document>> doStuff(
        @RequestBody JAXBElement<my.company.stuff.request.Document> requestBody,
        Principal principal) throws Exception {
    requestDetails.setRequestBody(requestBody); //set request body
    // Doing some suff here and returning the result
    return stuffService.doStuff(...);
}
```

Then inject `RequestDetails` in `ExceptionHandler` and use,

```
Document requestBody = requestDetails.getRequestBody();
```

Comment: Are you referring to `org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext`? If so it does not have a getRequestBody() method

Comment: Updated an answer. I hope its useful.

Comment: As I said in my question when the document does not pass XSD validation it will not reach the controller at all. The exception happens before reaching the controller and once it happens it gets passed to the error handler. Inside that error handler it would be good to be able to access request body and build up a more meaningful error response.

Comment: Then simply create a request interceptor and set the body there.

Answer (score 0):

when you trying to read request body there is error stream is already closed. With spring-boot 3.1.4 in the case of catching `MethodArgumentNotValidException` you can use `exception.getModel()` which returns `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>`. and you can find the class in object which one is Annoteted with `@RequestBody` in controller.

eg. RequestDto

```
   @PostMapping
   public ResponseEntity<> postRequest(@RequestBody RequestDto request)
   {
      // code
   }



   @ExceptionHandler({ MethodArgumentNotValidException.class })
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(final MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
        log.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);

        

        Map<String, Object> exceptionModel = exception.getModel();
        // exceptionModel.keySet() ["requestDto", "org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.requestDto"]
        RequestDto requestBody = (RequestDto) exceptionModel.get(new ArrayList<>(exceptionModel.keySet()).get(0));
        
        // TODO convert json or do what you want to do and store 

        return prepareErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, errors, Constants.METHOD_ARGUMENT_NOT_VALID_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be using `ControllerAdvice`

```
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    protected void handleHttpMessageNotReadableException(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,
                                                              HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request {
      // you have full access to both request and response
    }
```

Anyhow if this is not suited for your case, I think you can:

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

Comment: I can get HttpServletRequest out of my `WebRequest` request parameter this is not a problem at all. My question is how I get the request body. Trying to get it using the request InputStream does not work as the stream is already read all bytes out of it.

Answer (score -1):

you can add one more param HttpServletRequest and there you will get request.
Example:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class InvalidRequestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidRequestException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<BusinessLogicValidationError> handle(InvalidRequestException exception, HttpServletRequest request) {

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("some text");
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was not about getting the request but rather getting the request body.