# Using request body data inside exception handler spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to access my request body data inside my exception handler method.

This is my endpoint code :

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/items", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadItems( @RequestBody final List<ItemVO> l_items )
        throws ResourceAccessException, UnrecoverableException, NonFunctionalException, DataLockException, FunctionalException, Exception {
    
          // code here 
}
```

Now i want to access my l_items  data inside my exception handler method :

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<?>  fireWSException(Exception ex , final HttpServletRequest request)
{
    ErrorWSResponse errorResponse = new ErrorWSResponse();
    
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    
}
```

Who has an idea how can i do this please ?

Comment: If you catch HttpStatusCodeException, you can use the getResponseBodyAsString method

Comment: There are some solutions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502332/how-to-get-the-requestbody-in-an-exceptionhandler-spring-rest

Comment: @DGeorge thank you i will try your solution and give you feedback

Comment: @KajHejer thank you for your response,yes i saw this code but it seem too complicated i can't get what RequestContext is in this example and how to do so in my code.

Comment: @noussair Ok :) I hope you find a solution!