# Handling long string with IOUtils

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to handle MethodArgumentNotValidException in a Springboot application. My entry point is expecting a valid JSON object. I do intercept the error message correctly:

```
"message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 5, column: 7] (through reference chain: fr.ws.ui.model.request.RequestModel[\"data\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])",
```

That's great... Here is my exception handler implementation.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { MethodArgumentNotValidException.class, HttpMessageNotReadableException.class })
public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handleHttpMessageNotReadableException(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,
                                                                          WebRequest req) throws JsonProcessingException {
    // weird behavior, I got the json but not complete
    String output;
     try {
         output = IOUtils.toString(((ServletWebRequest) req).getRequest().getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
         System.out.println(output);
     } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
    ErrorMessage errorMessage = ErrorMessage.builder()
            .operationId(Utils.generateId())
            .status(RequestOperationStatus.ERROR.name())
            .message(ex.getMessage())
            .createdAt(new Date())
            .data(output)
            .build();

    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

Now, I want to retrieve the body of my request and I want to parse the content to extract data for building the ErrorMessage body. For this I used `org.apache.commons.io` library:

```
IOUtils.toString(((ServletWebRequest) req).getRequest().getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

The request contains several properties and a file in Base64 format.
It works fine but not totally: I do not retrieve the full request body, I do not get the request body start. My String seems truncated. How can i get the whole request as String ?

Comment: did u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502332/how-to-get-the-requestbody-in-an-exceptionhandler-spring-rest

Comment: I did see it. It has no relation with my issue. There the question is to know how to retrieve the request body when MethodArgumentNotValidException is thrown. I do get the content of my request. My issue is that i don't have the whole data of the request sent. 
1. I used ManagedBean to pass data to the whole application 
2. IOUtils.toString(((ServletWebRequest) req).getRequest().getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) returns the request body but incomplete (for me)... Thanks !