# How request-scoped bean injection works in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am aware that there are some similar questions on SO already, but please read on.

I am reading [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502332/how-to-get-the-requestbody-in-an-exceptionhandler-spring-rest), and in the accepted answer the author proposes the request-scoped bean injection into a singleton `@RestController` bean with a simple `@Autowired`. But how can it possibly work? I mean there is only one  `@RestController` bean in the Spring IoC context. And request-scoped bean is [by definition](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html) bean that is produced per http request basis. Therefore, each and every request that is handled by a controller, possibly concurrently, will have its own `RequestContext`.

But again `PersonController` is a single bean in IoC context, what exactly `RequestContext` would be injected? What if we have 5 concurrent requests on the same controller - what `RequestContext` will be injected in this case?

Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very high level, you can think that spring will create a AOP proxy around the actual bean instance and will inject this proxy into the controller. Any method invocation on the proxy instance will be intercepted by spring such that it will create or get the actual bean instance to invoke the actual method.

Every scope in spring besides singleton and prototype will be backed by a [`Scope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/Scope.html) implementation. In term of request scope , it is `RequestScope`. To better understand from codes, you can think that whenever you invoke any methods on that request scoped proxy , it will somehow get the actual bean instance by calling [`RequestScope#get(beanName,objectFactory)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/7aae97bcd469105ac2f2aa76ce93f38df455e3b9/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java#L42) which in turn get the bean from the `RequestAttributes` . The `RequestAttributes` will be stored in the `ThreadLocal` such that each thread will have its own instance.  If no beans can be retrieved , it will instantiate a new one and store it to the `RequestAttributes`.

Normally the implementation of `RequestAttributes` is `ServletRequestAttributes`. If you look at its [source codes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/225c9062a1b062564aab9439bbda54d0b1e471d9/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletRequestAttributes.java#L179) , you can then find that the request scoped bean instance is actually  stored as an attribute in the `HttpServletRequest`.

> What if we have 5 concurrent requests on the same controller - what
> RequestContext will be injected in this case?

Servlet container will handle these requests in separate threads. Each thread will has its own `ThreadLocal` to store its own `HttpServletRequest` which in turn store its own `RequestContext` in its attribute. So it is the `RequestContext` in the `ThreadLocal` of the thread that is used to process the HTTP request will be injected into the controller.

Comment: Very good explaination, thanks. Is there anything in official documentation that explains this? I have not found anything myself

Comment: thanks. don't aware the official documentation has such explanation. i make this conclusion and summary based on what i read the source codes