# Spring detect if client disconnect

Tags: spring-mvc, nginx, spring-webflux, haproxy, spring-restcontroller

This is the current architecture, I am working with

```
        (upload file)                          (WebClient RestAPI)    (Rest API)
Browser --------------> HAProxy ----> Nginx -----> Spring WebFlux ---> Spring MVC
```

I would like to send a request to remove cache from the server's Redis if Browser got disconnected by

- client's PC shutdown
- xhr abortion (AJAX, etc)
- browser's tab is closed
- losing the internet connection

1. Technically, can I possibly send a request to remove some cache in the server after the server detected the browser got disconnected? as the below

```
   eventClientDisconnect () {
       // remove some cache from Redis
       http.send('DELETE', 'http://localhost/user/1')
   }
```

2. Which is the best layer that I should trigger if the browser got disconnect? 
   `HAProxy, Nginx, WebFlux, or MVC`?

Thank you.

I apologize in advance if those questions are not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solutions. 
I can handle it in `Webflux` or `MVC servlet`.

**I.MVC Servlet** can be detected (when the request was finished)

- Client closes browser or tab
- Client PC's shutdown
- AJAX abortion
- Client disconnect by switching off the WiFi

```
@Bean
public Filter loggingFilter(){
    AbstractRequestLoggingFilter f = new AbstractRequestLoggingFilter() {

        @Override
        protected void beforeRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
            System.out.println("beforeRequest: " +message);
        }

        @Override
        protected void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
                   // Client closes browser or tab
                   // Client PC's shutdown
                   // AJAX abortion
                   // Client disconnect by switching off the WiFi
        }
    };
    return f;
}
```

[For any more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25513264/10258377)

**II.Webflux** can be detected only

- Client closes browser or tab
- Client PC's shutdown
- AJAX abortion

you use `doFinally { ... }` event to handle the above problems is enough.

But if you wish to handle **client disconnect** by switching off the WiFi. 
You may need to use the `WebSocket` dependency.

*This code may be working in Servlet not Webflux, but I am not sure, so you can try it.*

**Server**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
}
```

```java
public class GreetingHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        super.afterConnectionClosed(session, status);
        // Detected client disconnect here....
    }
}

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
        // Detected client connect here....
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
         session.sendMessage(message);
    }
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class RawWebSocketConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public WebSocketConfigurer webSocketConfigurer() {
        return new WebSocketConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addHandler(new GreetingHandler(), "/greeting").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:7010");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Client JS (http://localhost:7010)**

```
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7000/greeting");
```