# Client disconnection should abort the query execution in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Please anyone help out to get any reference or example regarding the below scenario

I have the Spring boot application where i have to detect the client disconnection (browser close) and abort the query execution if any

So here my code as snowflake query execution then outputstream.write  operation i tried to check the IOException and abort the query but my snowflake query will be executed as it is before the outputstream .So how can i get the notifictaion from query execution server when client disconnected is there any way please help out

Comment: Check this, maybe it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66406307/10277150

Comment: I should not use websocket protocol instead  internally there will be java socket .Actually i am trying to do ctrl+c to abort the api execution then in code outputstream.wrtite should throw exception IOException its not happening any other way to test the client disconnection  i just need the exception to be thrown when there is client disconnection